# speed up sox processing on multiple parts of the same file

Tags: sox

I am iterating over a long WAV file with sox like this:

```
loop, %loop_times%
    {
        curr_time := (A_Index - 1) * window_step
        RunWait, %comspec% /c ""%sox_path%" "%inputfilepath%" -n remix %chosen_channel% trim %curr_time% %window_len% stat 2>>"%temp_stderr_output_path%"" 
    }
```

The script itself doesn't matter (it's AHK), but the result is that I have many thousands of calls to sox (from console window) that take different parts of the same WAV file and, in this case, redirect stat stderr output to a txt file (I am trying to build an RMS volume map of the WAV signal).
i.e.:

```
    sox.exe input.wav -n remix 3 trim 0.000000 0.1 stat 2>>"c:\temp\sox.txt"
    sox.exe input.wav -n remix 3 trim 0.050000 0.1 stat 2>>"c:\temp\sox.txt"
    sox.exe input.wav -n remix 3 trim 0.100000 0.1 stat 2>>"c:\temp\sox.txt"
    sox.exe input.wav -n remix 3 trim 0.150000 0.1 stat 2>>"c:\temp\sox.txt"
    sox.exe input.wav -n remix 3 trim 0.200000 0.1 stat 2>>"c:\temp\sox.txt"
    sox.exe input.wav -n remix 3 trim 0.250000 0.1 stat 2>>"c:\temp\sox.txt"
    sox.exe input.wav -n remix 3 trim 0.300000 0.1 stat 2>>"c:\temp\sox.txt"
    sox.exe input.wav -n remix 3 trim 0.350000 0.1 stat 2>>"c:\temp\sox.txt"
    sox.exe input.wav -n remix 3 trim 0.400000 0.1 stat 2>>"c:\temp\sox.txt"
    sox.exe input.wav -n remix 3 trim 0.450000 0.1 stat 2>>"c:\temp\sox.txt"
    sox.exe input.wav -n remix 3 trim 0.500000 0.1 stat 2>>"c:\temp\sox.txt"
...
```

The problem is, it's very slow.

Is there a way to speed it up by somehow "keeping the WAV file open" between all the different sox calls?

Answer (score 0):

After trying out python, I found that the following solution satisfies me, except that I can't measure RMS for a window shorter than 0.4 seconds.
[python pyloudnorm get RMS values (loudness metering) for PCM WAV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75608134/python-pyloudnorm-get-rms-values-loudness-metering-for-pcm-wav/75608837#75608837)